# How to add cruisecontrol.net build step based on output of .NET code

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

I have written some code which checks a site for broken links using the IIS SEO toolkit API. The interface for the code is nice and simple, see below:

```
public interface ILinkChecker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks links in the website containing the supplied URL and returns a LinkCheckSummary instance detailing the results.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The URL.</param>
    /// <returns>A LinkCheckSummary instance detailing the results of the check.</returns>
    LinkCheckSummary CheckLinks(string url);
}
```

I can determine whether there are broken links or not by checking the returned `LinkCheckSummary` object.

I would now like to integrate this into our Cruise Control CI pipeline so that if the LinkChecker detects broken links, the build is broken.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap this in a [NAnt task](http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.com/2009/06/writing-custom-nant-task-part-1.html) or an [MSBuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx) and execute it as a part of the build.

Comment: Thanks - the NAnt link is very useful and clearly shows how to add a build task. However, it doesn't tell me how to 'break the build' in the manner of a failed unit test, for example. Do I just throw an exception? Return a particular type?

Comment: The convention is to `throw new BuildException('Reason of build failure');`. NAnt takes care of the rest.